# Draw line in cocoa

Tags: objective-c

I want to draw line on iPad using user points. How can I do that? Kindly reply if you know

Comment: type your title in a search engine...first hit is http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/Paths/Paths.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simple 2D graphics you'll want to use Quartz 2D.

This [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677984/where-can-i-find-examples-of-quartz-2d-drawing-on-the-iphone) has some good examples, and apple provide full documentation [here](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Also - see this very similar question: [How do I draw a line on the iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856354/how-do-i-draw-a-line-on-the-iphone)
The accepted answer includes instructions and sample code.

Comment: Using Quartz 2D we often draw paths to fixed points but what if we want to draw line where user drags on screen??

Comment: If that's what you're after then you should clarify your question.