# What are some great Quartz 2D drawing tutorials?

Tags: iphone, core-graphics, quartz-graphics

I'm searching for some great Quartz 2D drawing tutorials aimed at the iPhone.  I'm new to Quartz and want to start off with something easy and then progress to more difficult stuff.

Does anyone know of any Quartz 2D drawing tutorials that they would recommend?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I devoted an entire class to Quartz 2D drawing last semester in my advanced iPhone development course.  The video for that is available [on iTunes U](https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/advanced-iphone-development-spring-2010/id407243032), along with the rest of the class.  The course notes for that session can be found [here](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/sites/default/files/Spring2010CourseNotes/quartz%202d%20drawing.html), and I created a [sample application](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/sites/default/files/QuartzExamples.zip) to show off some more advanced Quartz drawing concepts.

Beyond that, I highly recommend reading the [Quartz 2D Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Comment: Thanks, your videos are really helpful!

Comment: +1 Great tutorials....really helpful

Comment: Why so many vote for this one! You have bad teaching method. No presentation, explain too much about Apple doc. I feel it's too boring

Comment: @iAn - Please do point me to your video series, so that I can take notes on how to properly present content.

Comment: I just a student, I think if you can simply the complicate things by a good presentation like this one : https://itunes.apple.com/en/course/developing-ios-7-apps-for/id733644550. It will help a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Start with Apple's [Quartz2D demo project](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/QuartzDemo/Listings/ReadMe_txt.html). Compile it, run it on your device, read the code while you use the demos in the app.

Comment: I've already done that.
Thanks anyways!!