# Learning Core Graphics

Tags: iphone, core-graphics

I'm doing iPhone programming and I need to learn about Core Graphics.
It looks Apple doesn't provide a programming guide for Core Graphics and I'm having hard times following the code that uses Core Graphics.

Do you suggest any reference or book for learning Core Graphics?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are some great Quartz 2D drawing tutorials?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463256/what-are-some-great-quartz-2d-drawing-tutorials)

Comment: When I typed my post title, the thread you are referencing to didn't appear, thanks for referring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start here [iOS Reference Library](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/index.html?section=Resource+Types&topic=Getting+Started#section=Resource%20Types) and type in Core Graphics. Also, check out 'Sample Code' and 'Graphics & Animation'. You will find that Core Animation tends to subsume Core Graphics, so reading about Core Animation might be helpful.

Comment: Thanks, this is the best thing I can get right now:   http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: Check out the sample code as well. I always find that useful because you can run it and then tweak it. For example, <http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/QuartzDemo/Introduction/Intro.html> and, to a lesser extent, <http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Touches/Introduction/Intro.html>

Answer (score 0):

I made a github repo with several examples of how to use some CoreGraphics features, it may be a starting point: [RPCGSandbox](https://github.com/raspu/RPCGSandbox).