# Detecting touches on a part of UIImageView

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiimageview

I have an image and it looks like a triangle but its area is a rectangle.
[image]

In this image there are two blocks (denoted by 1 and 2 in the image) and the whole rectangle is an image view.

I want to detect touches only on the first part of the image.

What to do for detecting touches only in this part?

Comment: What do you want to "detect" on it?

Comment: Actuly i want to detect only image portion not remaining space.

Comment: I understand, but what do you mean by "detecting" it? You want to clip/crop the image to that part? You want to tell where that triangle is located? Or what?

Comment: I want to perform touch only those portion which is actual image area.

Comment: Then you should probably subclass UIView and override the `touchesBegan:withEvent:` etc. methods.

Comment: So how can i create subview like triangle shape???

Comment: @DikenShah : If my Answer solved your Question then Mark it as Accepted, So that It can help Future Visitors.

Answer (score 2):

A `UIView` is always a **Rectangular shape**, you can't alter that. However, you could perhaps get the effect you want by using `CALayer` masking. Make a `UIView` and apply a custom mask to it, whereby the mask has the appropriate data in it for a triangle. Then any actual content you put in your `UIView` will only be visible in the appropriate **'triangle'** shaped area.

To make your mask layer, you can either use an **Image** (e.g. a png) or use **Core Graphics** to draw a triangle. There are certain things you can do :

- You can get help through this Beautiful [Link](http://www.blackpawn.com/texts/pointinpoly/default.html).
- There is [an example](http://cocoadev.com/wiki/MaskingACALayer) here.
- See also this SO Question:  [Learning Core Graphics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4028951/learning-core-graphics)
- You can check this Apple's [Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007533-SW1).

Hope It will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 2):

As H2CO3 said, you can subclass UIView (or UIImageView) and implement touchesBegan:withEvent: and co.
Then test whether the touch point lies within your region of interest. For your particular requirements (triangular half of image) the test is quite simple.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
   CGPoint touchPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
   if (touchPoint.x < touchPoint.y)
   {
      // touch in lower triangular half; handle touch however you like
   }
}
```

If you're subclassing UIImageView, don't forget to set its userInteractionEnabled property to YES.

Comment: As an alternative, one could simply add a GestureRecognizer onto a regular UIImageView and follow the given logic for testing the region. +1 for drafting a fully functional solution.

Comment: Till's idea of adding a gesture recognizer onto the image view, instead of subclassing image view, is better

Answer (score 1):

First Add this `UIImage` in `UIViewController` class  and then in this just add this method...

set the tag to your `UIImageView` like bellow...

```
 yourImageView.tag = 1;
```

and then use bellow method...

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    [touch locationInView:self.view];
    if([touch.view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]])
    {
        UIImageView *tempImage=(UIImageView *) touch.view;
        if (tempImage.tag == 1) 
        {
              ///Image clicked here, Do anything which you want here..your Image detect here...
              NSLog(@"Image clicked here");
        }
    }
}
```

i hope this help you

Comment: Thanks for answer.I did it but it detect whole imageview but i don't want to detect whole imageview but detect only some portion of imageview.

Comment: oh its not work with this code , but i will post if i detect touch with different part of image from my code..

Answer (score 1):

You must create an 90degree triangle from touched point (`point`) and then you must calculate if blue angle (**first check below image**) is bigger or smaller than red angle. If so than point is inside 2 else is inside 1

**Solution in swift:**

```
func calculateIfPointIsInsideTriangle(point: CGPoint, triangle_h: Float, triangle_w: Float) -> Bool{

    //    print ("intrare w=\(triangle_w), h=\(triangle_h), x=\(point.x), y=\(point.y)")

    let angle_triangle: Float = atan2f(triangle_h,triangle_w)

    let angle_point: Float = atan2f(triangle_h - Float(point.y), triangle_w - Float( point.x))

    if angle_point <= angle_triangle {
        //        print ("2")

        return true
    }
    //    print ("1")
    return false
}
```

Hope I'm not mistaken because in my case triangles were on the other side. For that case you should use

```
let angle_point: Float = atan2f(triangle_h - Float(point.y), Float( point.x))
```

**Beware**: iOS coordinate system is

(0,0) .  . . (1,0)

.

.

.

(0,1) . . . (1, 1)

and that is why for calculating `angle_point` you must use `triangle_h - Float(point.y)` and `triangle_w - Float( point.x)`

[image]

Sources:

https://www.raywenderlich.com/35866/trigonometry-for-game-programming-part-1

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/14602/what-are-atan-and-atan2-used-for-in-games