# how to set starting point (or starting angle) of a path described by CGPathCreateWithEllipseInRect?

Tags: swift, ellipse, skaction, cgpath

I have a sprite that follows a path described by CGPathCreateWithEllipseInRect. It always start at the right-most point (I guess because the default is to start at angle = 0). How do I make it start from the top-most point (at angle = π/2) ? My current code is like this:

```
    let pathCenter = CGPoint(x: frame.width/2 , y: frame.height/2)
    let pathDiameter = CGFloat(frame.height/4)
    let path = CGPathCreateWithEllipseInRect(CGRect(origin: pathCenter, size: CGSize(width: pathDiameter * 1.5, height: pathDiameter * 0.8)), nil)
    let followPath = SKAction.followPath(path, asOffset: false, orientToPath: false, duration: 6.0)
    sprite.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(followPath))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to draw your own path instead of using `CGPathCreateWithEllipseInRect`, adding points in an order that corresponds to where you want the sprite to start.

Try the method in this post: [How to draw a circle starting at the top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183785/how-to-draw-a-circle-starting-at-the-top), and then modify as needed.

Answer (score 1):

@PatrickLynch ... Thanks I was able to get my sprite starting from the top-most point of a circular path, like this...
`var path = CGPathCreateMutable()
CGPathAddArc(path!, nil, 100, 100, 100, CGFloat(M_PI_2) , CGFloat(2*M_PI + M_PI_2) , false)
var followArc = SKAction.followPath(path, asOffset: true, orientToPath: false, duration: 2.0)
sprite.runAction(followArc)`