# Tracing a Line iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer, uitouch

What I want to do is create a kids game where you have to trace a line. What I am trying to figure out is the best way to do this. I was thinking that I could use a transparent png with a line on it to use as reference. I know that you can analyze a png and create a shape out of the non transparent part but I'm not sure how to do that. Whats the best way about doing this? If using a PNG is good how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some reading -- start with the [Quartz 2D Programming Guide.](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/Introduction/Introduction.html)  I would personally use an approach utilizing paths rather than bitmaps.

You might also want to look at [Brad's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19679/brad-larson) [video](https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/advanced-iphone-development-spring-2010/id407243032) that he references [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463256/what-are-some-great-quartz-2d-drawing-tutorials).